# HTML troubles in standard Email app on Android tablet

Tags: android, html, css, email

I use HTML coding in email marketing.
Nowadays It is important to nice represent email offers both in standard and mobile version.
So, exist the certain tricks which help you to made your emails looks nice on mobile devices (without bugs and gaps).
For example, the most famous trouble is the tearing of content of email letter due to changing of text size by mobile device.
To ban this feature of device I use next css-trick:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    body {

        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;

}
```

This trick works fine if I check my email in mobile device browser.
But it is not work if I check it in standart app for viewing emails.

For example here are the screenshots made from Android Tablet PC in standart "E-mail" app (version 4.1):

[image]

You can see, that the content is torn because of the incorrect text size.

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using media queries is not 100% supported in all email clients (Gmail for example). Fortunately, this doesn't need to be in a media query.

A webkit specific declaration will only work in webkit based clients (mac for example).  See the [htmlboilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) (line 35), you could also add the ms prefix:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
```

I doubt this will address your Android tablet however. This may be something unavoidable, unless adding `!important` to your font-size can do the trick.